# How can I solve the missing Office Reference when building on DevOps?

Tags: c#, azure-pipelines, devops, assembly-references

I'm trying to compile a c# project on azure DevOPS but I get this error on the Build Solution step of the pipeline:

```
##[error]AddColumnLSCT\MainWindow.xaml.cs(3,22): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

If I try to locally build the project it works correctly without any error or warnings.
I've already added the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel as you can see in the attached image
[References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYir3.png), and the corresponding NuGet Package as you can see in this attached image [NuGet Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hxz4.png). How can i fix this?

Comment: In your .csproj file, what is the path to the  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Exce DLL?

Comment: I could not find the .dll  relating to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Exce DLL in the .csproj file. I've only found  these lines:
 `COMReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Core">
      <Guid>{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>8</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>primary</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>`

Comment: have you tried to remove this dependency and to re-add it pointing to nuget package?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito how can I see if it point the nuget package or not?

Comment: @TemoZat I don't know but you should just select the dll in pkg folder

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito the packages folder actually is empty, anyway  locally the project compiles correctly.